# Is that possible to use APM elastic for desktop application?

Tags: .net, vb.net, elasticsearch, apm

I have desktop application that use .net , i want to monitor performance that application. is that possible to use APM elasticsearch to monitor this apps?.. or any other tool that can monitor performance for desktop application?

Answer (score -1):

one of the solutions will use ["public api"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/apm/agent/dotnet/current/public-api.html) .

You can create manually transactions and set their types.

And inside transactions you can create manually spans.

For example, example with java api:

```
import co.elastic.apm.api.ElasticApm;
import co.elastic.apm.api.Transaction;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            Transaction transaction = ElasticApm.startTransaction();
            try {
                transaction.setName("ExampleTransaction");
                transaction.setType(Transaction.TYPE_REQUEST);
                // do your thing...
            } catch (Exception e) {
                transaction.captureException(e);
            } finally {
                transaction.end();
            }
        });
        thread.start();
        thread.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: Short answers with external URLs are considered low quality because the external content can move. Please ensure you include the key details in your answer. See [answer] for more info.